# Python Wifi Search Not Working

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, wifi

I'm sure there is a super easy answer to this question, but i'm new to python, and am having trouble finding resources on the internet that are specific enough to my problem. I'm trying to run a program that searches for wifi networks, and then outputs what it finds.

```
from wifi import Cell, Scheme
Cell.all('wlan0')
```

In the terminal I have already downloaded the packages wifi and cell.

Thank you in advance for any help given.

**EDIT:**

The error message as follows,

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "Search Wifi", line 1, in  from wifi import Cell, Scheme ImportError: No module named 'wifi'

Comment: And what's the problem? There's no question here.

Comment: opps. Sorry. I was just wondering what I was doing wrong? Is there an error in the implementation of the package?

Comment: How do you know there's a problem in the first place? Are you getting an error? What's wrong?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Search Wifi", line 1, in <module>
    from wifi import Cell, Scheme
ImportError: No module named 'wifi'

Comment: How did you install the wifi package?  In what directory is it installed?

Comment: i put in the terminal

Comment: $ pip install wifi

Comment: What command are you using to run your script?

Comment: pi@raspberrypi:~ $ pip show wifi
Name: wifi
Version: 0.3.8
Summary: 
Home-page: None
Author: None
Author-email: None
License: None
Location: /home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires: pbkdf2, setuptools

Comment: Okay, so `wifi` is installed for Python version 2.7.  What version of Python are you using to run your script?

Comment: i dont understand what command?

Comment: im using Python 2.7.13

Comment: how are you running/executing the script?

Comment: Im running the script through geany

Comment: Run this python script in geany: `import sys; print (sys.version)`.  This will tell us what version of Python geany is using.

Comment: Geany is using 3.5.3

Comment: Well that explains it.  The `wifi` package is installed for Python 2.7, but you're using Python 3.5.

Comment: Follow up questions:

Comment: how do i change versions